# Spring Integration : MessageDeliveryException : failed to send message

Tags: batch-processing, spring-integration

I'm newbie in Spring Integration Framework but I try to understand what is wrong in my configuration since several days, and I'm blocked ...
Perhaps you can see what is wrong.
It's pooling files from a directory and transforming the File Payload into a LaunchRequest (to launch a Spring Bath job).
My program detects when a file is created in the directory but doesn't send the file in the 'files' channel (MessageDeliveryException : failed to send message to channel 'files')

[...]

```
<int:service-activator method="launch" input-channel="files-requests"
output-channel="statuses">
   <bean class="org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler">
    <constructor-arg ref="jobLauncher"/>
   </bean>
</int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="files"/>
<int:channel id="files-requests"/>
<int:channel id="statuses"/>
```

[...]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Show, please, more config, especially for flie polling. And More StackTrace, of course

Comment: It is resolved, I have a probleme with the absolute path of the file. I can see it in putting <property name="strict" value="false" /> on my Reader to have the path of my file : I can see only the name of my file, not the complete path)

Comment: Glad to hear. Keep her steady!